# Best way to find all documents with 2 fields in mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i need help in finding documents in mongodb.
My schema is like below:

```
const users = new Schema({
      _id: ObjectId,
      facebookId: String,
      .....
      .....
})
```

I have 2 arrays for query like below:

```
const facebookIds = ['1', '2', '3']
const _ids = ['1', '2', '3']
```

At the moment, I am thinking of finding all the documents with `facebookIds` array first, getting their `_id`, concat the result with `_ids` array, and finally finding all the documents with resultant `_ids` array.

So, I want to know that what will be the best way to query the documents in one go, or this is the only way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, you will get the same outcome if you try with facebookId first and after that _id. Or will you use the _id array to find data in some other collection?

Comment: No, the collection will be the same for query, which is users but the problem is that some users have facebookId while others have null but i do have their _id, however the users with facebookId, i don't have their _id which i will have to find out. Now, i want to find all the users, sort them based on their online status and lastSeen parameters, paginate only 10 users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have 3 users in the collection with facebookId and another 3 without facebookId. You already have the facebookId of the first 3 data and _id of the last 3 data.

```
    [
  {
    _id: 1,
      facebookId: 10,
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
      facebookId: 20,
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
      facebookId: 10,
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
      facebookId: null,
  },
  {
    _id: 5,
      facebookId: null,
  },
  {
    _id: 6,
      facebookId: null,
  }
]
```

You can use [$or](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator and [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator for this

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      facebookId: {
        $in: [10,20,30]
      }
    },
    {
      _id: {
        $in: [4,5,6]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is a working [mongoplayground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DmbXBez3eKT)

Comment: Great, you can mark this answer as accepted if you want :)